# "Input string was not in a correct format" Visibility expression error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to create an expression to hide a certain value. I've used the expression in another cell without the **NOT** part and the expression works. But when I attempt to use it for the visibility expression I get the error. The data type is for **forderdate** is DateTime.

```
=Not(IIF(
 IIF( WeekDay(Today()) <> 2, 
       IIF(Fields!forderdate.Value=Today() OR Fields!forderdate.Value=DATEADD("d", -1, Today()),
            "**",
    ""), 
  IIF(Fields!forderdate.Value=Today() OR Fields!forderdate.Value=DATEADD("d", -1, Today()) OR Fields!forderdate.Value=DATEADD("d", -2, Today()) OR Fields!forderdate.Value=DATEADD("d", -3, Today()),
       "**",
      "")
       ),
       True,
       False))
```

Comment: I've not reallt digested the full expression but can you now just remove the `NOT` and reverse the `True`, `False` at the end?

Comment: When I do that I get the same error.

Comment: What's the error? Also try to put a new column in with the value set to your expression so you can see what it is returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Date field turned out to be the causing the problem. I used the `VAL`function to extract the Year portion of a field that is Year/Month/Name combination. Instead of going in to my expression and putting `VAL` before **forderdate** I referenced the textbox that contains the expression.

```
=IIF(VAL(ReportItems!Textbox315.Value),False,True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I excluded the `Not()` and switched the `True/False` like @Alan suggested, because its the same this way. The only mistake left could be your date field. This expression worked for me:

```
=IIF(
     IIF( WeekDay(Today()) <> 2, 
          IIF(CDate(Fields!forderdate.Value)=Today() OR 
              CDate(Fields!forderdate.Value)=DATEADD("d", -1, Today()),
              "**", ""), 

     IIF(CDate(Fields!forderdate.Value)=Today() OR 
         CDate(Fields!forderdate.Value)=DATEADD("d", -1, Today()) OR 
         CDate(Fields!forderdate.Value)=DATEADD("d", -2, Today()) OR 
         CDate(Fields!forderdate.Value)=DATEADD("d", -3, Today()),
         "**", "")
     ) ,False, True)
```